# How to sign a buffer in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, signature

I'm trying to sign a buffer in NodeJS with this code

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+
  Buffer.from("dm7NmAXbOZQ3RX//RPdrjuJgyqfqUFUA2qMt461BjTc=", 'base64')+
  "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(Buffer.from("P101RhuYuayFsAsa633mBzGPGn761sXjXiEPFV8sCY=", 'base64'));
var signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'binary');
console.log(signature);
```

But it give me this error

```
internal/crypto/sig.js:83
  var ret = this._handle.sign(key, passphrase, rsaPadding, pssSaltLength);
                         ^
Error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `"P101RhuYuayFsAsa633mBzGPGn761sXjXiEPFV8sCY=".length === 43`. Doesn't look like a valid base64 string. You're probably missing one character

Comment: Concatenating a string with a buffer makes no sense. Either you pass a buffer of binary data, or you pass a string with base64-encoded binary data that might be prefixed by `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`, but you wouldn't pass a mixture of them.